# How to get socket io server to put different data packages in their correct server variables?

Tags: variables, socket.io, package, client

Like a lot of people here, I'm new to socket.io and have a question about the server scripting.

Is it possible for the client to send, say data type A, B or C depending on their choice, to the server, and the server to understand it's type and place it in the corresponding A, B or C variable server side?

I'm quite sure it's possible, and if it is, could someone point me in the direction where I could find the correct syntax for coding this?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do, because there is like so many ways to do that.

One way:

Client side:

```
socket.emit('data', {dataString: "string", dataInt: 42});
```

Server side:

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  if(data.dataString)
  // do something
  if (data.dataInt)
  // do something else
});
```

Another way:

Client side:

```
socket.emit('data', "hello world");
socket.emit('data', 42);
```

Server side:

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  if(typeof data === "string")
  // do something
  else if(typeof data === "number")
  // do something else
});
```

Comment: I see, I have the emitting down, my question is more along the lines of, how do you break down incoming data packages if they carry multiple bits of data, like data A, B and C. Do data packages carry titles or something to differentiate them or tell what kind of game data they carry?

Comment: Oh I see, I was hoping for something a bit more specific, but if specifying by string or number or something along those lines can separate it out that should help.